# Bayes theorem and conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have a problem like this:

> Seventy-eight percent of the light aircraft that disappear while in
>   flight in a certain country are subsequently discovered. Of the
>   aircraft that are discovered, 60% have an emergency locator, whereas
>   85% of the aircraft not discovered do not have such a locator. Suppose
>   a light aircraft has disappeared. (Round your answers to three decimal
>   places.)
>
> a) If it has an emergency locator, what is the probability that it
>   will not be discovered?
>
> b) If it does not have an emergency locator, what is the probability
>   that it will be discovered?

I know D = discovered = .78, and so D-complement = not discovered = .22

Thanks

Comment: Images, especially ones that are low quality or that do not contain complicated formatting, are highly discouraged. You are encouraged to type all your posts and include all your work. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I can even read what this says.  Can you do some typing and tell us what the question is? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy done pls look at question

Comment: try to define $A$ - aircraft that are discovered. $B$ - aircraft that have an emergency locator.

Comment: @d_e I can figure out P(A), it is 0.78. But how to figure out P(B)?

Comment: you have more data. you know that $P(B/A) = 0.6$ and another data. you should use all this data to find $P(B)$

Comment: @d_e ok, so how can I calculate that probability from the given info? I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @Kingamere, see my answer below. let me know you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define:

$A$ - aircraft that are discovered.

$B$ - aircraft that have an emergency locator.

We know from the question that: $P(A) = 0.78$, $P(B\mid A) = 0.6$ and $P(B_c\mid A_c) = 0.85$. so using Bayes theorem we can deduce that:
$$ \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} = 0.6 \Longrightarrow P(B\cap A) = 0.468$$
$$ \frac{P(B_c\cap A_c)}{P(A_c)} = 0.85 => P(B_c\cap A_c) = 0.187$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Ok I see, I understand how you got to this point. So to calculate P(B), do I use the law of total probability? Sorry, I've been struggling with this one for a while.

Comment: yes. you know $P(A_c \cap B) = P(A_c) - P(A_c \cap B_c) = 0.033$. so you can find $P(B)$ . $P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(A_c \cap B) = 0.501$.

Comment: ahhh ok, thanks, I understand now. That was the challenge for this problem. The rest of the problems are easy now. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the law of total probability, where$$
P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^c)P(A^c).
$$